# Make a function with Optional arguments Listable

Tags: function-construction, optional-arguments

```
ClearAll[fun]
Options[fun] = {key -> "k", val -> ""};
fun[OptionsPattern[]] := {OptionValue[key]-> OptionValue[val]}

fun[key -> "k", val -> "v"]
(* {"k" -> "v"} *)

fun[val -> #] & /@ {1, 2, 3}
(* {{"k" -> 1}, {"k" -> 2}, {"k" -> 3}} *)

MapThread[fun[key -> #1, val -> #2] &, {{"x", "y", "z"}, {1, 2, 3}}]
(* {{"x" -> 1}, {"y" -> 2}, {"z" -> 3}} *)
```

How is it possible to make **fun** Listable and get the same results

It seems I am missing something basic here, and I cannot find a relevant answer.

Comment: Are you asking for, e.g., `fun[key -> {"x", "y", "z"}, val -> {1, 2, 3}]` to return the same thing as your last output and whether this could be achieved with the attribute `Listable` on `fun`?

Comment: @Xavier yes indeed, I want to set the Listable attribute on fun and return the same result.

Comment: @ShutaoTANG surprisingly this does not work directly for functions with rules as optional arguments ! You have to do the transformation of Xavier first.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[fun]
Attributes[fun] = Listable;
Options[fun] = {key -> "k", val -> ""};

fun[OptionsPattern[]] := fun[OptionValue[key], OptionValue[val]];
fun[k_, v_] := {k -> v};

fun[key -> "k", val -> "v"]
(* {"k" -> "v"} *)

fun[val -> {1, 2, 3}]
(* {{"k" -> 1}, {"k" -> 2}, {"k" -> 3}} *)

fun[key -> {"x", "y", "z"}, val -> {1, 2, 3}]
(* {{"x" -> 1}, {"y" -> 2}, {"z" -> 3}} *)
```

Comment: thank you, this is a nice trick. If I understand well you transform the function with the optional arguments to a function with normal arguments. So I assume that if you do have some large body of this function to work out, you do all the processing in the body of fun[k_, v_], correct ?

Comment: @Athanassios Per transformation - Yes, exactly, and these normal arguments correspond to the values of the options. Per processing - Yes, and the processing should be done knowing that each of the arguments `k` and `v` in `fun[k_, v_]` correspond to one value only.